# Including Collider Variables in Prediction

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, bias, causality, accuracy

When the goal is to estimate a causal association between X and Y in the regression framework, one should not condition on (include as covariates) collider variables (common causes of both X and Y) since doing so may introduce spurious/non-causal associations that bias the coefficient estimate for X (Berkson's paradox).

My question: can including collider variables as potential predictors in a classification/machine learning framework also cause problems when accurate, generalizable, and useable *prediction* of Y is the goal? I.e. does the causal problem also lead to a prediction problem?

Answer (score 6):

No, causal problems do not lead to prediction problems. In fact, in your case, the "problem" may actually allow us to improve our prediction!

Suppose the graph is simply $X \rightarrow C \leftarrow Y$. Then $X$ and $Y$ are d-separated, which means that they will be completely independent. Also, the effect of $X$ on $Y$ is identified without the need to condition on further variables. Estimation will show that $E[Y|do(X = x)] = E[Y|X = x] = E[Y]$. THis also means that $X$ alone is not useful to predict $Y$.

However, if we do not care about the causal effect, but merely want to predict $Y$, we will find that

$E[Y|X = x, C = c] \neq E[Y]$

because conditioning on the collider $C$ opens up a path between $X$ and $Y$. This will mean that a reliable variable selection procedure should pick up both $X$ and $C$ as relevant predictors. At the same time, conditioning on $C$ is invalid for causal inference.

One comment on wording: $E[Y|do(X = x)]$ is the mean of $Y$ if you set $X = x$ externally. Estimation of this quantity from data allows you to **predict** what happens when you $do(X = x)$. $E[Y|X = x]$ allows prediction of $Y$ when you *see* $X = x$. Both tasks may be useful, depending on the context.

Comment: Very helpful. One clarification that may get to the reason for my worry: including C will change the weight/coefficient on X  away from the true causal value. If we then predict Y using these C and X weights to make decisions about something we care about, can't this classification lead to some negative allocation/fairness outcomes since we now allocate based off a biased X and C that wouldn't necessarily be dealt with in cross-validation?

Comment: Are you thinking of something like: Race and unobserved credit risk affect your location of residence, and Y = credit default is just a function of credit risk? Then a regression of default on race and location will give a non-zero race coefficient.

Comment: That is a good example of how unfairness could arise out of an unmeasured important confounder similar to the "red car" scenario in the car insurance example. Then making decisions about default would be unfair since race will play a role where it shouldn't (even if we include race or exclude). But I was wondering if a case of even measured colliders may also result in a similar unfairness result since the "effect"/weight on, say race, will change (or even flip sign) if a collider is included.

Comment: I am not sure I can follow. In the race/location example, when you compare a model with race only (zero effect, as it is d-separated) and with both race and location, the weight on race in the latter case could change dramatically, because location is a collider. In general, discrimination in algorithmic-decion making is a subtle topic. You may find p. 2043 of Zhan/Bareinboim, "Fairness in Decision-Making", helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @JulianSchuessler. You should consider causal inference if you will make inference (forgive the redundancy) on the learnt model (i.e. the variable associations). But for mere black box prediction, geenerally you may not need to find the true causal relationships.

Having said so, causal information is much more desired in most problems than associational one. Causality is the fondation for data-driven decision making. Believing in predictions obtained from some data have a lot of risks specially for generalization. Thus this would only be useful in the same distribution of your training data, which is normally violated.

Importantly, you should modify a conceptual mistake in your question. **Colliders are *not common causes* of X and Y but *common *effects****. Common causes are confounders. Confounders must be conditioned on to obtain the the true causal effect contrary to colliders.